# How does the caller know that there was an error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please see the stored procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPerson2

AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    DECLARE @Count AS INT;
    SET @Count = 1 / 0;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'there was an error';
END CATCH
```

I can call it like this:

```
EXECUTE getperson2 ;

IF @@ERROR > 0
    PRINT 'there was an error outer';
```

I was thinking that when I call it: 'there was an error outer' would be printed to screen.  However, it is not.  How does the caller know that there was an error.  Do I have to create an output variable to hold the error code and then test if this is greater than 0?

I am trying to understand this in the scenario of a nested transaction.

Comment: Where this procedure called? Is it from App or from another SP?

Comment: @ Selva TS, either really.  In the example in my question it is called from an SQL Agent Job.

Answer (score 1):

You "consumed" the error by having a `CATCH` handle it.  Use [`RaIsError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) in the `CATCH` to report an error to the caller.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPerson2

AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- Scope is this stored procedure.
DECLARE @LocalTransaction AS BIT = CASE 
WHEN @@TranCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END;
BEGIN TRY
    IF @LocalTransaction = 1
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- Do your work here.
    --   You can use   RaIsError   to throw an exception, e.g.
    --   if validating an input fails.
    DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE (
        Thing INT NOT NULL);
    INSERT  INTO @MyTable (Thing)
    VALUES               (42),
    (NULL);
    IF @LocalTransaction = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Save the exception.
    DECLARE @ErrorLine AS INT = Error_Line();
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR (4000) = Error_Message();
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber AS INT = Error_Number();
    DECLARE @ErrorProcedure AS NVARCHAR (126) = Error_Procedure();
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity AS INT = Error_Severity();
    DECLARE @ErrorState AS INT = Error_State();
    DECLARE @NewLine AS CHAR (2) = Char(13) + Char(10); -- '\r\n'.
    -- Rollback only transactions when there is an active transaction that we started.
    IF Xact_State() <> 0
       AND @LocalTransaction = 1
        ROLLBACK;
    RAISERROR ('%s%s#%i [Proc: %s/Line %i]', @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorMessage, @NewLine, @ErrorNumber, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine); -- Exit with the exception.set @ErrorSeverity = 16;--case when @ErrorSeverity > 5 then @ErrorSeverity else 6 end;
    RETURN @ErrorNumber;
END CATCH;
RETURN 0;


GO
DECLARE @Error AS INT = 0;

EXECUTE @Error = GetPerson2 ;

PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST (@Error AS VARCHAR (10));

SELECT *
FROM   sys.messages
WHERE  message_id = @Error
       AND language_id = 1033;
```

Comment: I have tried the example code.  The error is not reported back to the caller.  It appears as a fatal error.

Comment: You can modify `@ErrorSeverity` in the `CATCH` block to make a fatal error nonfatal or vice versa. The example code just repeats the original exception without additional functionality, e.g. adding a custom message explaining what failed.

Comment: I have tried setting the errorseverity to 1 but still the error is not passed to the caller.  Here is the caller code: exec getperson2
If @@ERROR > 0
print 'there was an error outer'.  The message is not printed to the screen.

Comment: @w0051977 - `RaIsError`, `@@Error` and `EXECUTE` certainly don't get along as well as one might hope. I've updated the example to return the status and included a sample of getting the status and displaying the corresponding messages.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you confirm that you do have to use 'return'.  There are a few questions on here where the answerer implies that you do not.  +1 by the way.

Comment: `RETURN` was the only method that worked for me (using SQL Server 2008 R2). It certainly wasn't my first guess based on the documentation.

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor - You seem to have a significant issue with users failing to format TSQL to your standards. May I inquire as to what issue you believe you are addressing? Is it simply exercising a pretty printer for a few points of reputation or something more critical?

Comment: @HABO - Cant blame you for thinking that but I cant read unformulated code and I do not bother with formatting every code, Just the ones that interest me. One thing though, RAISERROR is being deprecated which means you may want to stop using it going forward.

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor - Would you be so kind as to provide a citation for the deprecation of `RaIsError`? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx) MSDN article indicates that support for an old syntax (`RaIsError 42 'Answer'`) has been removed, but the newer syntax (`RaIsError( ... )`) is still supported with no indication that it will be deprecated. I certainly don't want to be writing obsolete software, nor misleading anyone else.